# Building error at @parcel/transformer-js "cannot access a scoped thread local variable without..."

Tags: algolia, parceljs, preact

I have a project with Parcel and Preact (to implement Algolia Autocomplete Search) and I suddenly got an error while `npx parcel build theme/app-home.tsx --log-level verbose`.

It worked before and I'm working with git but I can't found what changed to break the build.

The error:

```
 Building app-home.tsx...
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'cannot access a scoped thread local variable without calling `set` first', /Users/runner/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/scoped-tls-1.0.0/src/lib.rs:168:9
 Build failed.

@parcel/transformer-js: cannot access a scoped thread local variable without calling `set` first

  Error: cannot access a scoped thread local variable without calling `set` first
  at Object.transform (/Users/cozarkd/Documents/GitHub/projectX/node_modules/@parcel/transformer-js/lib/JSTransformer.js:365:31)
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
  at async Transformation.runTransformer (/Users/cozarkd/Documents/GitHub/projectX/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Transformation.js:617:5)
  at async Transformation.runPipeline (/Users/cozarkd/Documents/GitHub/projectX/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Transformation.js:366:36)
  at async Transformation.runPipelines (/Users/cozarkd/Documents/GitHub/projectX/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Transformation.js:244:40)
  at async Transformation.run (/Users/cozarkd/Documents/GitHub/projectX/node_modules/@parcel/core/lib/Transformation.js:170:19)
  at async Child.handleRequest (/Users/cozarkd/Documents/GitHub/projectX/node_modules/@parcel/workers/lib/child.js:217:9)
```

The tsx file:

```
/** @jsx h */
import {
  autocomplete,
  AutocompleteComponents,
  getAlgoliaResults,
} from '@algolia/autocomplete-js';

import algoliasearch from 'algoliasearch';
import { h, Fragment } from 'preact';



const appId = 'theappid';
const apiKey = 'theapikey';
const searchClient = algoliasearch(appId, apiKey);


/* const querySuggestionsPlugin = createQuerySuggestionsPlugin({
  searchClient,
  indexName: 'database_query_suggestions',
  getSearchParams() {
    return {
      hitsPerPage: 5,
    };
  },
  
}); */



autocomplete({
  // debug: true,
  container: '#autocomplete',
  placeholder: 'Escribe aquí, sin miedo',
  openOnFocus: false,
  defaultActiveItemId: 0,
  autoFocus: true,
  getSources({ query }) {

    return [
      {
        sourceId: 'plantag',
        getItemUrl({ item }) {
          return item.url;
        },
        getItems() {
          return getAlgoliaResults({
            searchClient,
            queries: [
              {
                indexName: 'database',
                query,
                params: {
                  hitsPerPage: 10,
                  clickAnalytics: true,
                  attributesToSnippet: [
                    'name:10',
                    'nombre'
                  ],
                  snippetEllipsisText: '…',
                },
              },
            ],
          });
        },
        templates: {
          item({ item, components }) {
            return <ProductItem hit={item} components={components} />;
          },
          noResults() {
            return 'No hay plantas coincidentes :(';
          },
        },
      },
    ];
    
  },
    // Default Navigator API implementation
    navigator: {
      navigate({ itemUrl }) {
        window.location.assign(itemUrl);
      },
      navigateNewTab({ itemUrl }) {
        const windowReference = window.open(itemUrl, '_blank', 'noopener');
  
        if (windowReference) {
          windowReference.focus();
        }
      },
      navigateNewWindow({ itemUrl }) {
        window.open(itemUrl, '_blank', 'noopener');
      },
    },

});

function ProductItem({ hit, components }: ProductItemProps) {
  return (
  <div className="c-single-result">
    <a href={hit.url} className="aa-ItemLink">
      <div className="l-flex-container">
        <div className="aa-ItemContent">
          <div className="aa-ItemContentBody">
            <div className="aa-ItemContentTitle">
              <components.Snippet hit={hit} attribute="nombre" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="aa-ItemContentSubtitle">
                <components.Snippet hit={hit} attribute="name" />
          </div>
          <div className="aa-ItemActions">
            <button
              className="aa-ItemActionButton aa-DesktopOnly aa-ActiveOnly"
              type="button"
              title="Select"
              style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}
            >
              <svg viewBox="0 0 30 27" width="30" height="27" fill="currentColor">
              <path d="M10.0611 23.8881C10.6469 24.4606 10.6469 25.389 10.0611 25.9615C9.47533 26.5341 8.52558 26.5341 7.9398 25.9615L0.441103 18.632C0.4374 18.6284 0.433715 18.6248 0.430051 18.6211C0.164338 18.3566 0.000457764 17.994 0.000457764 17.594C0.000457764 17.3952 0.0409356 17.2056 0.114276 17.0328C0.187475 16.8598 0.295983 16.6978 0.439798 16.5572L7.9398 9.22642C8.52558 8.65385 9.47533 8.65385 10.0611 9.22642C10.6469 9.79899 10.6469 10.7273 10.0611 11.2999L5.12178 16.1278H13.5005C20.9565 16.1278 27.0005 10.2202 27.0005 2.93233V1.46616C27.0005 0.656424 27.672 -1.90735e-06 28.5005 -1.90735e-06C29.3289 -1.90735e-06 30.0005 0.656424 30.0005 1.46616V2.93233C30.0005 11.8397 22.6134 19.0602 13.5005 19.0602H5.12178L10.0611 23.8881Z"/>
              </svg>
            </button>

          </div>
        </div>


        <div className="aa-ItemIcon aa-ItemIcon--picture aa-ItemIcon--alignTop">
            <img src={hit.image} alt={hit.name} width="40" height="40" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  );

  
}
```

I can provide more info if needed. Did some search but I couldn't find anything related to Parcel with that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to repro the problem, and it looks like this might be a bug in parcel related to the JSX pragma at the top of the file (see [github discussion here](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/6605#issuecomment-907637695)). If you remove this line, it should compile fine:

```
/** @jsx h */ <--delete this line.
```

Parcel will automatically detect which JSX pragma to use for your project based on finding `preact` as a dependency in `package.json` (see [documentation](https://parceljs.org/languages/javascript/#jsx)). You can also manually control it with a `tsconfig.json` file like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "jsxImportSource": "preact"
  }
}
```

(This bug should probably still be fixed, but hopefully this is enough to help you work around it. I filed [a github issue here](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7234)).

Comment: wow, you arrived just on time. I was starting to make a fresh project to try to debug which part failed. I wouldn't probably notice that because I thought that was just a comment.
Thanks, working now.